# Difference between $(this) and $("#id") in a each loop in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jquery. I know the question is stupid but I'm missing some concept here.
Here's the problem:

```
$("input.integers").each(function(index) {

    console.log("----");
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + " " + $(this).val()); 
    console.log($(this).attr('id') + " " + $("#"+$(this).attr('id')).val());
    // the next log is here just to show a direct selection. I'm concerned about the two logs above this one 
    console.log($("#myId").attr('id'), $("#myId").val());

    that.setModelData($(this).attr('id'), $(this).val());
});
```

Here's the output:

```
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: '----'
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 61 of 90
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'myId '
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 61 of 90
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'myId 123'
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 61 of 90
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: [ 'myId', '123' ]
```

the tag is input. How come `$(this).val()` is empty and `$("#"+$(this).attr('id')).val()` contains the right value?

UPDATE:

The karma test:

```
it('the model must be updated', function(){

    $("#myId").val("123");  

    $("#save-process").click();
    server.respond();

    expect(fdtView.model.get('myId')).toBe("123");

});
```

The fixture:

```
<input id="myId" name="myId"
    class="integers" type="text" />
```

Comment: are you sure you are getting the empty value for the first one.. cause that looks fine to me..

Comment: @BalintBako the ID is unique

Comment: It works like a charm: http://jsfiddle.net/balintbako/U8YYE/

Comment: @bipen no, the first log is 'myId ' so doesn't print nothing, the second log is 'myId 123'

Comment: @BalintBako Yep, works for me as well (Chrome 28).

Comment: Show us your html markup.

Comment: @BalintBako I posted the test and the html of the fixtures

Comment: @YD1m I posted it, it's a regular input builded using a bootstrap builder found on github

Comment: @dierre Can you give us the results of putting `console.log(this);` within the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have to say this was a problem with karma and not with jquery.

We are using Backbone.js and the view is loading the template in the definition of the view:

```
template : _.template($("#mytemplate").html()),
```

Karma when loads the tests will go in exception if it doesn't find the fixtures so we added in a file called fixtures.js the fixtures at startup:

```
loadFixtures('viewtemplate.html','mytemplate.html');
```

*(@Blame)* Someone added in the `beforeEach` of jasmine test suite this code:

```
beforeEach( function() {
    loadFixtures('currentStepContainerFixture.html', 'mytemplate.html');
```

So the fixtures got loaded **twice**.

When I was using in my code:

```
 console.log($(this).attr('id') + " " + $(this).val()); 
 console.log($(this).attr('id') + " " + $("#"+$(this).attr('id')).val());
```

Basically the first log was about the current element, whereas the second log was about the first input having that id.

That's why we had this strage behaviour. I have to say that some kind of exception thrown for the presence of two element with the same id, *would have been helpful*.

```
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 61 of 90
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'myId ' --> current $(this)
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux): Executed 61 of 90
PhantomJS 1.6 (Linux) LOG: 'myId 123' --> first occurrence of "#myId"
```

I do not deserve those four points, the problem was between the monitor and the keyboard. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

In you loop, **this** match with $("input.integers") selector. So, jquery has in memory this selector. $("#myId") is an unique selector and for each loop, jquery search this element and analyse it. it's just a coincidence that the two elements are the same because you html code is:

```
<input class="integers" id="myId" />
```

However, if you are many input with same CSS class, **this** will be different.

An example with multiple input.

HTML code:

```
<input class="integers" value="toto"/>
<input class="integers" value="titi"/>
<input class="integers" value="tata"/>
<input class="integers" value="tutu"/>
```

JS code:

```
$("input.integers").each(function(index) {
console.log("Value = "+$(this).val);
}
```

Console log:

```
Value = toto
Value = titi
Value = tata
Value = tutu
```

So to answer your question, if `this.val()` is different from `$("#"+$(this).attr('id')).val())` is that the selector that loads this is not good.

Comment: Should I use something like $(this)[index] ? I mean, I've always considered this to point to the current element of the set selected by $("input.integers")

Comment: Why would you use a index. With a selector, jquery use this to define a unique element. I have added an example with multiple input.

Comment: You said **`this` match with `$("input.integers")` selector** but this is **not true**: inside the `each` callback, `this` is the **current** input, **not** the whole collection!

Comment: I think I should clear up that the third print is there just to show the direct selection of the element. What I'm concerned about are the first to log messages-

Comment: @MatteoTassinari exactly, that's why I had the follow-up question.